# JSON if condition Shopify Pipeline Theme

Tags: json, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to implement an if condition in JSON for Shopify. The Pipeline Theme has the option to include custom color swatch pictures by tweaking the swatches.json code. However there is a major problem with this: I have multiple products with the same color names and I can only link one color name with a swatch picture once. So now I can only use the same swatch pictures for all products, which is not feasible.

I now would like to include an if condition to only only show the swatches for the corresponding products and prevent these swatch pictures from showing for the wrong products.

I've tried it as followed:

```
if (product.type= "*product type name*") 
    {
    {
      "Ozean Türkis": "*file name.jpg*"
    },
    {
      "Bordeaux Rot": "*file name.jpg*"
    },
    {
      "Wald Grün": "*file name.jpg*"
    },
    {
      "Schiefer Grau": "*file name.jpg*"  
    },
    },
```

This returns the error message "Error: Invalid JSON: unexpected token".

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: JSON isn't code, it's pure data.

Comment: Meaning there is no way to add an if condition?

Comment: Not in a JSON file, no.

Comment: without working with JSON, what is your if statement look like?  I am confused on your description.  The purpose of swatch is to do a selection (product variant). when you disable that swatch, how can customer select?